# Give column name to values rows

Tags: sql, union, alias, derby

In Apache Derby, I'm generating some values using this statement:

```
select * from (
    select 10 as DISTANCE_KM from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 union
    select 15 as DISTANCE_KM from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 union
    select 18 as DISTANCE_KM from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 union
    select 21 as DISTANCE_KM from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 union
    select 25
) as DISTANCE
```

Which returns:

```
|DISTANCE_KM|
|-----------|
|10         |
|15         |
|18         |
|21         |
|25         |
```

There is a more concise way to generate similar results:

```
select * from (values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE
```

which returns:

```
|1          |  <---- I'd like this column to be called DISTANCE_KM
|-----------|
|10         |
|15         |
|18         |
|21         |
|25         |
```

Is there a way to alias the returned column as `DISTANCE_KM`? This is what I've tried, but it didn't work:

```
select "1" as DISTANCE_KM from (values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE
```

p.s. I'm not permitted to change the schema - so I can't store the values in their own table.

Comment: Can you try this: `select * from (values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE(DISTANCE_KM)` or `select * from (values 10 AS DISTANCE_KM, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE`?

Comment: How about `select * from (values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE (DISTANCE_KM)`?

Comment: You should rather use standard SQL syntax for the values clause `values (10), (15), (18), (21), (25)`. I am surprised that Derby accepts `values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have db2 on hand, but this might work:

```
select *
from (values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE(DISTANCE_KM);
```

If not, then this will work:

```
with distance(DISTANCE_KM) as (
      select *
      from (values 10, 15, 18, 21, 25) as DISTANCE
     )
. . .
```

Comment: Apache Derby does not support common table expressions, but the first solution will work.

Comment: Great answer Gordon. The first solution works perfectly